# Getting a response from a website for a particular request using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Can anyone please tell me how to :
a user gives source,destination and date and requests the availbale trains?
so this is the request I want to make to erail.in website..

How can I get response from that site and display it in my webpage..
using cURL in php..
please help me...thanx in advance..

I'm new to this stuff..I want to learn and also provide me some links..how to proceed with and what all can I do with curl..

I have tried like this..

```
$params=array(
  'txtStationFrom'=>'SC',
  'txtStationTo'=>'MAS',
  'adate'=>'26-6-2013'
);

$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.erail.in");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result=curl_exec($curl);

print $result;
?>
```

But this directly displays the whole webpage...
please help me I have to learn this..and I'm not getting anything..

Comment: cURL has done its job of getting you the source of the page. Now you need to parse the source (for example with DOMDocument) and pull out the train times. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: It is showing the home page not the expected page i.e.,not displaying the page along with the available trains.

Answer (score 1):

This particular site is dynamically loading the data with JavaScript, and the data is returned mostly as a bunch of numbers and codes. In order to scrape it, you would have to figure out how to properly form the URL for each request.

Here's a sample of the data returned:

```
Central~BCT~16.30~08.35~16.05~1111111~~~~~~~~1110000000~~~~~~~~~~~RAJDHANI~9012~2~1~0~2013-06-06~2018-06-07~1384~86~RAJDHANI:1384:4065,2250,2615,0,2250,0:2395,1345,1555,415,1345,0:1725,1005,1150,365,1005,0:0,0,0,0,0,0:0,0,0,0,0,0:0,0,0,0,0,0:0,0,0,0,0,0:0,0,0,0,0,0:0,30,0,0,0,0~0~0~~60~1~2952~Composition of Train: 1A-1,2A-4,3A-9,PC-2
```

Scraping should be done responsibly so as not to overload the server. The best policy is to communicate with the company about what you want to do.

Comment: How did you get that data..can you provide the code and what do you mean can't I proceed with my project..Can't I fetch data from that site according to the user's specification of source,destination and date...?

Comment: Fiddler is a free application that shows the HTTP requests that your browser is making and the requests received. In just a few minutes, I was able to visit a page with data, and with Fiddler, I could see the URL and the data returned.

Comment: As far as the code is concerned, once you have a proper URL, you can use cURL as you're doing but make it a GET request instead of a POST. As far as how you want to proceed with your scraping, that is for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

you can not get details from erail.in, because erail.in does not provide any API facility. But IRCTC provide API to get train details, but it is not free of cost.

Comment: They don't provide API's. So, after searching for a very long time I found that curl and HttpWebRequest/HttpWebresponse helps us in getting responses for a particular request or like that..I'm not sure though..